# Docusign Connect not consistently publishing envelopes

Tags: docusignapi

On demo.docusign.net I have configured Connect to publish signed/completed envelopes to a public URL (https on port 443) with the following config details:

- Allow Envelope Publish
- Enable Log (maximum 100)
- Envelope Signed/Completed
- Recipient Signed/Completed

Connect however is not consistently publishing to my URL. Since that configuration was done we have had at least 30 signed/completed envelopes, but only 4 published envelopes! There are no failures logged for the envelopes not published. The completed envelopes are all being signed using embedded signing.

Why are some (the majority) of the signed/completed envelopes not being published?

Answer (score 0):

Whats the response logged in DocuSign connect Records view?

If your webhook is rejecting the post for some reason but still returning a HTTP 200 status, DocuSign won't consider ir a failure, by example (it happened to me).